# Touchpad does not work on 17.10, but it did on 14.04

Tags: touchpad

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 (I had 14.04 installed). Since then, my touchpad does not respond. When I use a mouse it works perfectly.

My laptop is a Packard Bell

Comment: i did : sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
then sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
nothing seems to change.
then when i write "synclient -l" the answer is "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Comment: And when i write "xinput list" it returns 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                      id=7 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13             id=8 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                     id=6 [slave  keyboard (3)]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give the exact model of your laptop and  add the `xinput` output there. We can't read it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't disabled the touchpad on your keyboard? It is toggled by (<kbd>Fn</kbd>)+<kbd>F6</kbd> on my Packard-Bell laptop.

Comment: I am sure yes. I tried (Fn+F6) right now twice and nothing changes.
Thanks for reponding

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be another Wayland problem. If I run 17.10 on Wayland on my Packard-Bell EasyNote laptop the touchpad is unresponsive but running 17.10 on Xorg the touchpad works perfectly.

When I boot into GDM I get the choice of Ubuntu (which is on Wayland) and Ubuntu on Xorg. If you have the same menu I suggest you use Ubuntu on Xorg as a workaround for the time being.

I will report the bug.